# Trying to read user input from a textbox and print it out underneath in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

when I run this the "You entered: *insert text here*" appears for a second and then disappears and the text box clears on its own. I spent 3 hours and I can't see where I'm making my mistake. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
<title> Basic JavaScript </title>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 
function Copier() {

var firstWord= document.getElementById("Word1").value; 
document.write("You entered: " + firstWord);

}

</script>

</head>
<body>


<form> 

Word Number 1: 
<input type = "text"  id = "Word1" > 
<br> 

<button onclick = "Copier()">Copy Text Box 1</button>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the form tag.

In case you are using a form tag around your input, the browser assumes that there should be a method defined like:

```
<form action="post/get" url="some-file.php">
```

As soon as your JavaScript has grabbed the input, it get's flushed out by the form (re)action, which is pointing to no file specified.

Just leave the form tag and grab the value by the input field itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title> Basic JavaScript </title>
<style>
input[type="text"] {
    border: 1px solid #565656;
    padding: 2px;
    color: black;
}
#display {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
}
</style>
<script type = "text/javascript"> 
function Copier() {
var firstWord= document.getElementById("Word1").value;
var box = document.getElementById('display');   
box.innerHTML = "You entered:" + firstWord;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Word Number 1: 
<input type="text"  id="Word1" > 
<br>
<button onclick = "Copier()">Copy Text Box 1</button>
<div id="display"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, the form tag was throwing me off!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `document.write()` as it is dangerous. Create a separate element with its own `id` and use `innerHTML`:

```js
function Copier() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "You entered: " + document.getElementById("Word1").value;
}
```

```html
<form> 

  Word Number 1: 
  <input type = "text"  id = "Word1" > 
  <br> 

  <button onclick = "Copier()">Copy Text Box 1</button>
  <p id="output"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using what user 'user2521387' said about the form tag. You should drop the form tag, and if you don't want to use innerHTML you could do something like this:

```
function Copier() {
    var firstWord = document.getElementById("Word1").value;
    var box = document.getElementById('display');

    //clear all childs of div with id 'display'
    while (box.firstChild) {  // whilte first child is valid
        box.removeChild(box.firstChild); // removes first child
    }
    var p = document.createElement("p"); //create p tag
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("You entered:" + firstWord));

    box.appendChild(p); //add p tag to div 

}
```